# Where does Pydio variable AJXP_DATA_PATH points in CentOS?

Tags: nginx, centos, php, centos7, pydio

I'm trying to make a Pydio installation on a CentOS 7 system with Nginx + Php-fpm. I did not found a comprehensible guide, but still I think I've managed.

I get this error when I try to access Pydio:

> Impossible write into the AJXP_DATA_PATH folder: Make sure to grant write access to this folder for your webserver!

I'm running php-fpm and nginx services as nginx user and nginx group. I've set AJXP_DATA_PATH in /etc/pydio/bootstrap_conf.php and checked that user nginx owned and had permissions to that folder. I also checked that user nginx owned and had permissions to /usr/share/pydio.

No matter what I do, I get the same error. I think that maybe AJXP_DATA_PATH gets set by some other file or maybe does not read bootstrap_conf.php.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

May be write action is blocked by SELinux. Try to disable SELinux for testing.